# how to preload collection from server

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone.js-collections

Am developing a hybrid app with backbone.marionette and phonegap.
Am having issues with my collections not being ready in time for use in a view utilize them because they are still being fetched from the server.
How can i preload my collections so my views can use them when the app starts?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the collection data ?

Comment: the collection data is used to populate views

Comment: You can do the preloading or just subscribe to the backbone collection/model change or reset event. Or you can prefetch and store it in localstorage.

Comment: The users have to be authenicated before the collections can be fetch from the server

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply rendering them on screen using views. You can work with [Marionette.CollectionView](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md) which will add the collection's models to the views as they are added.

```
var MyCollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
   //add Item View and other required fields
});

//myView will listen to the myCollection's events such as add, remove etc and will update itself
var myView = new MyCollectionView({collection: myCollection});
myCollection.fetch();  //Will fetch the data from the server

//Render the view whenever you wish.
myView.render();
```

If you really want to preload. You can first fetch and than render the view on success callback.

```
collection.fetch({
   success : function(
      view.render();
   )
});
```

Comment: When you instantiate a new marionette view and pass it a collection, it will automatically update on collection sync. `var myView = new MyCollectionView({collection: myCollection}); myCollection.fetch();`

Comment: `myView.render()` isn't even needed. See line 27 of [marionette.collectionview.js](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/marionette.collectionview.js)

Comment: @thibauts why is so. in order to actually render the collection view you have to call render. right? i don't see any auto rendering in the marionette code for the collection view itself.

Comment: see my comment above.

Comment: point taken. but that's on reset event. You either specify the {reset: true} in the fetch call, or take care of rendering order manually. Sometime you wish to render a wrapper view first and than the collection view.

Comment: You're right. I wondered too why my code worked when I built it. Now (I think) I know why. Check [backbone.js](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js) lines 860-861. `set` is called, which, line 744, fires an `add` event on the model being added. Then the model's event percolates to the collection's `_onModelEvent` line 930. And now back to [marionette.collectionview.js](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/marionette.collectionview.js) line 25. This is why it works, I suppose. Facts not checked, I havn't done my homework !

Comment: that's why we discuss and have such community sites. We learn every time. I also learned about the reset event and collection view. thanks.